# Es Justo que las Preguntas Generadas con ayuda de IA, no sean tratadas igual que las respuesta

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta, chatgpt

Estoy 100% de acuerdo en que ***todo*** lo que sea generado con apoyo de las I.A no sea aceptado en el sitio...

Esto quiere decir que si una respuesta es considerada plagio por venir de una I.A... De esta misma forma deben ser tratadas las preguntas como esta:

[Cómo configurar Windows para que los puertos USB se abran y cierren a determinadas horas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/617057/315134)

Estamos ante una pregunta que claramente usa una referencia de código dado por I.A que pudo ser sacado de cualquier lugar sin darle el crédito a su Autor (Plagio) ...

***Nota:*** la pregunta tienen otros problemas los cuales no mencionare ni entrare en detalles ya que no es el objetivo de este post.

***Por otro lado:*** al preguntar a los Moderadores Electos por que no se le da el mismo trato que a una pregunta, la respuesta fue tan simple como decir:

> "porque es una pregunta y no una respuesta" sin dar una mejor
> explicación...

Lo cual no satisface mi necesidad de ser justo con los usuarios del sitio, esto no tiene lógica o carece de total Neutralidad, Sentido de apoyo hacia los usuarios... por lo cual no me dan una explicación del por qué, a una pregunta si se le permite y a una respuesta no... Prácticamente aquí hay algo que no se quiere decir...

Al indagar más sobre el asunto la siguiente explicación fue dada:

> la gente que le pregunta a una IA y despues viene a preguntar aca, es
> caso a caso... capaz que pregunto, refactorizo y despues tuvo un
> problema.. no es lo mismo...

Definitivamente para mi esta respuesta crea más dudas... me estáis diciendo que dependiendo del contexto... una pregunta o una respuesta Generada por IA puede ser o no ser aceptada en el sitio? ***(ambiguedad)***

***Tenemos dos escenario de estudio en las preguntas:***

1. el usuario usa ChatGPT, el código no funciona (plagio de código) y lo trae para que le demos una solución.
   **(Aceptado)**
2. el usuario usa ChatGPT, asumismo que re-factoriza el código (posiblemente no hay plagio de código) y paso algo y no le funciona, lo trae al sitio buscando ayuda.
   **(Aceptado)**

**otros 2 Escenario similares en las respuesta:**

3. el usuario usa ChatGPT, copia el código tal cual (Plagio de código) lo trae y lo coloca como respuesta.
   **(Usuario sancionado)**
4. el usuario usa ChatGPT, re-factoriza y comprueba que el código funciona, lo trae y lo coloca como respuesta.
   **(Usuario sancionado)**

No estoy de acuerdo como se "Aceptan" los escenarios 1 y 2, deberían recibir el mismo tratamiento que 3 y 4...

### ¿Estaríamos de acuerdo en que las preguntas deben recibir el mismo tratamiento que las respuesta?

Actualmente solo se aplica a respuestas:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

### ¿o en su efecto debe existir una politica para las preguntas?

Que aclare y detalle los conceptos bajo los cuales se aceptan las preguntas.

Comment: Usualmente el usuario que busca respuestas en la IA es porque no tiene muchas luces de lo que está haciendo y por eso trae esas respuestas aquí como una pregunta. Al final no le estas contestando a la IA (que generó el código), si no al OP. Por otro lado, contestar usando una IA es mal visto porque se supone que aquí son expertos quienes le dan luces a esos que no lo ven claro. Si alguien no conoce el tema, foldea (como decimos acá) y lo deja a otro. No veo ningún motivo para usar IA en respuestas.

Comment: y para las preguntas @aeportugal ? 

Comment: @Excorpion si, es lo primero de lo que escribí, pero quizás no me expliqué bien. Los OP buscan primero en la IA, esta le da una respuesta que no se acomoda perféctamente a lo que quieren y usan esa respuesta como una pregunta en SO. Yo no lo veo tan mal, siempre y cuando ese código esté próximo a lo que se está buscando. He visto casos que el OP pone una pregunta con código de IA que no está ni cerca de lo que describe. Pienso que en estas últimas ni se debe perder el tiempo y cerrarse de plano.

Comment: @aeportugal estoy de acuerdo pero si viste lo que redacto el de la pregunta que comparti... los que usan IA y vienen aqui con preguntas, no les interesa aprender ... simplemente quieren una solucion lista para ejecutar ... y de plano esto para mi ya raya en el abuso ... por otro lado no hay una politica aclaratoria y es contradictorio que tengamos que responder a preguntas generadas en una IA, mas no podamos usarla para responder esas mismas preguntas ...

Comment: entonces si de plano metemos todo en el mismo saco... y nos safamos de esto ...

Answer (score 1):

Comentaré exactamente lo que tu me compartiste por chat:

### [Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Y destaco los siguientes fragmentos:

> los usuarios copian y pegan información en las respuestas sin validar que la respuesta proporcionada por GPT sea correcta

> Los moderadores están facultados (a su discreción) para emitir suspensiones inmediatas de hasta 30 días a los usuarios que estén copiando y pegando contenido de GPT en el sitio, con o sin previo aviso o advertencia.

Entonces, debemos dejar en claro, que **actualmente, lo prohibido es responder haciendo uso de chatGPT sin validar que la respuesta sea correcta.** 
Si yo como usuario, hago uso de ChatGPT, copio el código, lo edito, lo corrigo, y verifico que la respuesta sea correcta, y luego publico mi respuesta en el sitio, ya dejo de ser participe de la prohibición, por que eh resuelto los conflictos que generaba el uso de ChatGPT.

En tus puntos sobre respuesta, el caso 3 es el actualmente sancionado, pero el 4 no.

Si a tu parecer el uso de ChatGPT durante las preguntas debiese ser prohibido, pues lo respeto, más no lo comparto. Que el sujeto haya intentado solucionar sus problemas con el uso de la herramienta demuestra que ah intentado cosas, y trata de resolverlas, antes de venir a preguntar al sitio.

Y, respondiendo a:

### ¿o en su efecto debe existir una politica para las preguntas?

Si, apoyo que exista una política que agregue la normativa actual (o nueva) para las preguntas, y así los conflictos como este, no sean necesarios.

Comment: esto no responde a mi propuesta... estas respondiendo/trancribiendo lo que ya sabemos todos... y que menciono en mi propuesta...

Comment: y te menciono algo muy importante por el cual se prohibio el uso de ChatGPT y que esta en las politicas: _**GPT corre el riesgo de romper la confianza de los lectores de que nuestro sitio proporciona respuestas escritas por expertos en la materia.**_

Comment: entonces por que deberiamos aceptar problemas que no vienen o no fueron creadas por Humanos ...

Comment: Eso es una aseveración desmesurada. No todos somos expertos en informática, pero todos podemos dar una respuesta. Y los problemas son creados por humanos, ChatGPT no genera problemas de manera autónoma, es un buscador más que una IA a mi parecer, pero el que te atiende tiene la chapita de "empleado nuevo" y apenas sabe donde está el frasco de las propinas. Ahora, yo quiero algo, yo busco una solución, y encontré a este sujeto que tiene respuestas y soluciones, yo las pruebo, no me funcionan, me frusto con el, y voy a preguntar a otro lado... en ese otro negocio no me atenderán? o si?

Comment: es lo que dice la politia no yo...

Comment: A tu nueva pregunta, la modificada de "...en su efecto debe existir una politica para las preguntas?". Si, y sería bueno que, sin importar el resultado, la política aclare la situación de las preguntas y el uso de ChatGPT. Ya sea que termine diciendo, si, se admiten, o no, se prohiben.

Comment: en efecto si llevas algo chiviado a la garantia ... a que te resuelvan gratis ... te rechazan

Comment: No somos garantía, podrías llamar garantía a la documentación de lo que usas, pero no a SO.

Comment: tampoco cobramos ...

Comment: es un servicio gratuito igual que una garantia aqui resolvemos problemas ... de programacion ...

Comment: tu usaste un ejemplo de un negocio ... aqui no nos pagan ... no tengo la obligacion de recibir todo lo que traigan los usuarios ...

Comment: Si dije un negocio, pero no somos la garantía oficial, somos maestros chasquitas, o negocios establecidos hace años (ergo, no somos todos expertos, pero todos podemos dar una respuesta). Si tu como negocio PHP, no quieres recibir clientes con problemas de ChatGPT, estas en tu derecho, pero yo, como tu competencia, si quiero recibirlos. (por eso te dije que deberías ignorar la etiqueta de chatgpt si no las quieres ver)

Comment: esa no es una respuesta correcta... el problema no es lo que yo vea ... es como se tratan las preguntas ...

Answer (score 0):

Si, es justo que reciban un tratamiento distinto.

Creo que la mayoría entendemos que la IA es una herramienta que ha llegado para quedarse. Y los que nos oponemos a su uso en el sitio no es que tengamos una resistencia al cambio, si no que vemos algunos problemas en ella. Los que veo yo son:

- La IA genera respuestas que siempre parecen razonablemente correctas, motivo por el cual, detectar si existe un error es más complejo que en los casos de respuestas generadas por humanos. Esto implica un mayor trabajo para moderar respuestas
- En la mayoría de los casos donde vi que se alertaba de una respuesta incorrecta, el usuario borra la respuesta. En cambio, en situaciones similares cuando es un humano lo habitual es que la corrija. Esto es importante, porque hay muchos usuarios que buscan preguntas sin responder para responder, entonces al haber habido una respuesta ya no la revisan.
- En los primeros días hubo un descontrol de su uso, habían usuarios que respondían cada 3 minutos lo que fuera, lo que llevaba un exceso de trabajo en la moderación
- Existe un tema de "confianza", entiendo que cuando alguien busca una respuesta en el sitio, lo hace buscando una respuesta de un humano. Si el OP quisiera una respuesta de la IA, él puede ir y generar su propio *prompt*, no se requiere de un intermediario.
- Luego existe el tema de la gamificación, que si bien a algunos no les gusta es parte importante del sitio, los privilegios se obtienen con puntos. Usar IA para responder es como si en el ciclismo alguien usara una bicicleta con motor.

Esas serían mis razones, y ninguna aplica para las **preguntas**, por eso creo que deben aplicar distintos criterios. Además, muchos exigen al OP un intento de resolver su propio problema, usar la IA me parece un intento honesto y que al día de hoy es tan habitual como usar google.

Y por último, hay un tema práctico. En el caso prohibir el uso en las preguntas lo que va a suceder es que los OP sencillamente no declararán que lo usaron, esto dará más problemas, porque cuando usuario coloca un código uno es capaz de medir su nivel y dar una respuesta acorde para que el OP la entienda. Cuando el OP declara que el código es de ChatGPT yo ya sé que ese no es su nivel real, en cambio sí lo oculta es probable generar una explicación donde el OP no tenga los conocimientos para comprenderla.

---

Entiendo que el motivo principal de prohibir la IA en el sitio fue el plagio. A mí siempre me pareció un motivo flojo, pero bueno yo soy ingeniero no abogado. Qué derechos de autor puede tener un par de líneas de código??, o como en el caso de la [pregunta citada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/617057/c%C3%B3mo-configurar-windows-para-que-los-puertos-usb-se-abran-y-cierren-a-determinad), un par de comandos?? para mi ninguno.

Comment: toda tu respuesta gira en torno a dejar respuestas... cuando mi cuestion es sobre las preguntas ...

Comment: por que las *PREGUNTAS* Deben recibir un tratamiento distinto ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Quizás he entendido mal tu pregunta. Cuando tú dices "tratamiento distinto" yo entiendo que estas comparando *preguntas vs respuestas*. Por tanto, hablar de las respuestas es relevante y de este modo yo intento explicar porque en mi opinión si deben tener tratamientos distintos, porque la IA en las *respuestas* generan problemas que en las *preguntas* no lo hacen

Comment: claro que es relevante pero has redondeado en lo que ya se sabe de las respuestas... yo no estoy preguntando por como funciona en las respuesta... estoy proponiendo que las preguntas reciban el mismo trato... repetir 1000 veces como se tratan las respuestas ... no demuestra nada... ya que se sabe ...

Comment: Es que no son hechos desconectados. La prohibición de la IA no nace de una apreciación antojadiza, nace de problemas que origina al sitio y a los usuarios. Los problemas más relevantes (para mi) son los que he expuesto. Esos problemas aplican exclusivamente a las *respuesta* (NO a las preguntas). Por tanto, veo correcto que exista un tratamiento distinto.

Comment: yo n ohe dicho que sean hecho desconectado ... he dicho que estas enfocandote en el hecho que ya todos conocemos y esta normados ... te agradesco leas nuevamente mi post... por que estas argumentando lo mismo que esta en la ayuda ... nada nuevo ... tu respuesta redunda en no ser una respuesta ...

Comment: Yo entiendo que estas pidiendo una opinión a la comunidad (ya que está la etiqueta discusión). Mi opinión es que la IA da problemas solo en el caso de las respuestas no en las preguntas. Los motivos son los que he descritos y son los que yo aprecio, no los que están en el centro de ayuda, y si estos coinciden bien por mí.  Por otro lado, considero que eres tú el que no ha dado ningún motivo razonable para extender la prohibición a las preguntas, apelas a un sentido de justicia cuando las preguntas y respuestas son cosas distintas y no tienen por qué aplicar las mismas reglas para ambas

Comment: el post es sobre problemas en las preguntas al usar I. A? o sobre otra cosa que se parece?

Comment: tu respuesta es una respuesta trol... desvías totalmente a los lectores del objetivo de post... por lo Menos sabes cual es el objetivo???

Comment: Lo de trol sobra absolutamente. Yo te respondí lo que te preguntaste

Comment: no puedo decir que absolutamente has desviado el objetivo de la publicacion... en ningun punto respondiste las dos preguntas:

Comment: **¿Estaríamos de acuerdo en que las preguntas deben recibir el mismo tratamiento que las respuesta?** si/no y (porque)

Comment: **¿o en su efecto debe existir una politica para las preguntas?** si/no y (porque)

Comment: tu respuesta es del estilo: existe otra norma.... y por eso se rigen las respuesta ... (no tiene nada que ver con las preguntas)

Comment: Tu pregunta está en el título *"Es Justo que las Preguntas Generadas con ayuda de IA, no sean tratadas igual que las respuesta?"* Y te respondo en la primera línea de mi respuesta: *Si, es justo que reciban un tratamiento distinto*. El motivo de mi opinión te lo explico por 5ta vez: **porque en las respuestas dan problemas, no así en las preguntas**

Comment: Entonces estas otras 2 preguntas: *"¿Estaríamos de acuerdo en que las preguntas deben recibir el mismo tratamiento que las respuesta?*"  Es la misma pregunta del título, pero planteada de forma distinta. Mi respuesta que no deben recibir el mismo trato por los motivos ya mencionaos: y *¿o en su efecto debe existir una política para las preguntas?* No, porque no veo que la IA cause problemas, es más veo que es un intento justo por parte del OP de resolver su problema

Comment: estas mal enfocado, estas respondiendo al titulo y no al contenido del post... si bien el tutulo es una breve explicacion de la duda en general... no es el centro de informacion o a lo que se debe responder ... tu responde al contenido no al titulo... si solo tye has enfocado en el titulo ya veo por que tu respuesta se sale de contexto ...

Comment: responde en tu respuesta, no en los comentarios ... a nadie le interesa leer esta discucion ...

Comment: agrega algo que "Esas serían mis razones, y ninguna aplica para las preguntas" Si aplique a las preguntas ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152329/discussion-between-yussef-and-francisco-nunez-ia-lover).